# Custom Background Image per Page

Tags: images

Is it possible to send an image url via custom fields to the get_background_image function?

Comment: Yes. What is your actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

You really just need to check the source.

[`get_background_image()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/theme.php#L1228) uses [`get_theme_mod()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/theme.php#L880), which applies the [`theme_mod_{$name}`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/theme.php#L896) filter. So...

```
function alter_background($name) {
  // return something apporpriate for the theme mod
}
add_filter('theme_mod_background','alter_background');
```

Note: the "name" component may be different. Use `var_dump(get_theme_mods());` to work out what you need.